# query de busca no cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Quero fazer uma query que encontre a data, mas a query abaixo está encontrando mesmo quando não passo valor ou quando é um valor que não tem nada a ver com data:

```
$busca = $this->Despesa->find('all', array('data_despesa' => '2'));
```

Nesta query aí não era para retornar nada. Mas está trazendo tudo, como se fosse um `select * from nomeDaTabela`.

O que há de errado?

Estou querendo fazer sql fora do padrão do framework, como seria? Já vi que é algo mais ou menos assim: `$this->query("codigo dml");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que acontece é que você se equivocou nos valores do segundo parâmetro. O método [`find()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-Model.html#_find) espera como segundo parâmetro um *array* com uma ou mais das seguintes chaves: *'conditions', 'limit', 'recursive', 'page', 'fields', 'offset', 'order', 'callbacks'*.

Para usar condições como você pretende, deve utilizar a chave **conditions**, que é um *array*, assim:

```
$busca = $this->Despesa->find('all', array('conditions' => array('data_despesa' => '2015-10-21')));
```

Para a segunda dúvida, com o método [`query()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) você pode escrever toda sua sentença, puro *SQL*, sem utilizar o modelo do *CakePHP*.